# If array isset, do something?

Tags: php, arrays, isset

I am posting multiple checkboxes, and putting them into an array - for example: "tags[]"

When posting them, I am imploding them with commas.

If NO tags are checked on the form, and then posted, I get errors as the script is trying to implode something that isn't there.

I have tried using something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['tags'])){ 
    $tags = implode(", ", noescape($_POST['tags'])); 
}
```

What is the best way to check if it exists, then implode it?

isset, array_key_exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it in one line, in this situation `isset` and `array_key_exist` would give you the same result but then you may want to check if `$_POST['tags']` is an array...

```
$tags = isset($_POST['tags']) ? implode(", ", noescape($_POST['tags'])) : null;
```

or

```
$tags = (isset($_POST['tags']) && is_array($_POST['tags'])) ? implode(", ", noescape($_POST['tags'])) : null;
```

You can test here : http://codepad.org/XoU4AdsJ

Answer (score 2):

That should work:

```
if (isset($_POST['tags']) && is_array($_POST['tags'])){ 
    $tags = implode(", ", noescape($_POST['tags'])); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(array_key_exists('tags',$_POST))
{
..................
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!empty($_POST['tags'])) {
   $tags = implode(", ", noescape($_POST['tags']));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) before imploding so your implode only works if your imploded var is an existing array. Returns 0 if it is not set as well :)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Answer (score 1):

I'd use is_array() and count():

```
if (is_array($_POST['tags']) && count($_POST['tags'])>0){ 
    $tags = implode(", ", noescape($_POST['tags'])); 
}
```

Comment: If `$_POST['tags']` happens to be a string one day, this will crash cause a `count(string)` will return `1` as you can see here :http://codepad.org/AVfZS3qO

Comment: You're right. I just corrected my answer to include a is_array().

Answer (score 1):

Actually, an easier way to do this would be to do something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tags[]" value="none" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="Tag 1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="Tag 2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="Tag 3" />
```

And then remove the default value.

Obviously this would still cause errors if some malicious user decided to send a post to your script without any data at all.